# Multiple viewcontroller segue and execute function swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, viewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

*Hello I'm new in writing code on swift and I've been looking around the internet on how to do this and I haven't found any example o help me solve my dilemma. If someone knows how to help me, please respond.*

I'm working with two view controllers:
On the first viewcontroller(1) I have a label with the app name and under it I placed two buttons.

One that says **English** and the other that says **Spanish**. (I've connected each button with a segue on storyboard to the second viewcontroller that has its own cocoatouch swift file)

On the second view controller I have one label. (LabelA)
I've placed two functions in the file.

```
 func englishone (){
  labelA.text = "Welcome" }

 func spanishone (){
   labelA.text = "Bienvenido"}
```

I want the func englishone to execute on the secondviewcontroler when I press the English button on the first ViewController and to execute func spanishone when I press the Spanish button.

The only solution I've been able to make it work with is creating a third view controller. The SecondViewController is the English Function one and the ThirdViewController is the Spanish Function one. But with this solution if I create any new language Buttons in the first Viewcontroller I would have to create the same amount of extra viewcontrollers. (That wouldn't be an efficient design nor coding tactic.)

I believe that I should use a if statement on the secondeviewController, one that checks if button English was pressed or if button Spanish was pressed. However I'm quite not sure how to do that.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

From your first view controller, you can implement 
`prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` method.

You must add segue identifiers to all of your segues in the storyboard, and in `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` method you should ask for `sender.identifier` to check if it's pushing to Spanish, English, or other language.

Then, in your second view controller you must add a var that holds which language you're using. You'll use that var to define which method you're going to execute.

So, your second view controller needs to add an enum with the available languages, and have a var to store the selected language:

```
enum AvailableLanguages: Int {
    case Spanish
    case English
    case German
    case French
}

var language : AvailableLanguages!
```

From your first view controller, you should set your second's view controller var value in the `prepareForSegue(_:sender:)` method, accessing it with `segue.destinationViewController` property. This is how your prepareForSegue method should look like:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    switch segue.identifier! {
    case "englishSegue": (segue.destinationViewController as! LoginViewController).language = .English
    case "spanishSegue": (segue.destinationViewController as! LoginViewController).language = .Spanish
    case "frenchSegue": (segue.destinationViewController as! LoginViewController).language = .French
    case "germanSegue": (segue.destinationViewController as! LoginViewController).language = .German
    default: (segue.destinationViewController as! LoginViewController).language = .English //Or your default language
    }
}
```

Finally, once your second view controller appears, you should read the `var`'s value to select which method to execute:

```
switch segue.identifier! {
    case "englishSegue": englishone()
    case "spanishSegue": spanishone()
    case "frenchSegue": frenchone()
    case "germanSegue": germanone()
    default: englishone() //Or your default language
}
```

I think this is an exercise project, but in case it's a real project, the correct way to support multiple languages is using Internationalization for iOS. Read this documentation to understand how to internationalize your apps: [Apple Internationalization Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Comment: Thanks LucasIt89, although Im not sure what you me mean by adding a flag indicator on the secondviewcontroller. Can you show me what you mean?

Comment: Also what would I do if I add two new buttons French and German? In the example you gave me if I'm not wrong you're using a bool (true/false) that  wouldnt work with more options. How would I do It?

Comment: I edited my answer to add support to more than one language, and explaining more about how to achieve it. If what you're trying to do is to support multiple languages, I recommend not to follow this approach, but to use Internationalization tools in Xcode, so you won't need to do this for all of your view controllers.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question LucasIt89, Actually its a quiz game.